# AWS Datapipeline to Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am in the process of taking over a set of data pipelines on AWS.  They are all built using the AWS graphical editor tool.  The pipelines are getting complex and my goal is move them to code and have them versioned.  We are a ruby shop so besides of the AWS ruby gem is there another tool or framework I should use to do this?  Any resources, blogs, docs I can follow that would be helpful and easy to follow (aws docs could be better).

Answer (score 1):

Datapipeline supports a JSON definition format. The format is described in these links:

- [Pipeline Definition File Syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-writing-pipeline-definition.html)
- [Pipeline Object Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-objects.html)

From the Architect, you can export your existing pipelines as JSON by following the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-view-definition.html).

Commit these JSON files to your source control, and run/migrate/deploy them using the AWS CLI like this:

```
aws datapipeline create-pipeline --name mydpl --unique-id mydpl
aws datapipeline put-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id df-xxxxxxxxxx --pipeline-definition file:///mydpl.json
aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-xxxxxxxxxx
```